# svg inline chart path style not working

Tags: javascript, css, svg, path

I have made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSeagoe/gcx92zbv/) showing that a certain block of style code does work to change a chart "path" line from solid fill black to no fill steelblue.  The style is taking effect.  Note that this example is taken directly from chapter 20 of the book "Beginning JavaScript Charts" by Fabio Nelli which you might find online.  This book says to add this code to see the style take effect:

```
<style>
    path {
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 3;
        fill: none;
    }
    line {
        stroke: black;
    }
</style>
```

If I add the code in  tags in the head section (as the book suggests in Listing 19-1), it doesn't work, whereas it works in the fiddle, so presumably the code has to be in a CSS file for it to work?  Tested it in Chrome & IE.  Maybe there's some little syntax thing I'm doing wrong, or maybe the book is wrong, but I don't see it.

Comment: What does the chart markup look like? If the path and line elements in the chart have CSS with higher specificity then it won't be overridden.

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* — this is not a useful description of the problem. Are you saying the CSS styles were not applied, or did nothing appear at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much tweaking, the issue was that I had a comment in the style element which was incorrect format for css and was breaking the style functionality.

This was not shown above nor in the fiddle, so no wonder nobody could help.

The bug came from copying directly from the book "Beginning JavaScript Charts", Chapter 19, Listing 19-1, which contains this snippet:

```
<style>
// CSS Style here
</style>
```